# Using next_sibling with font color in BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to get data after a certain link with text map, but it doesn't work when the data after the link is colored. How do I get that?

Currently, I am using next_sibling, but it only gets the data points that are not red.

The HTML is like this.
I can read the number from here

```html
    <a href="http://scedc.caltech.edu/recent/Maps/118-36.html" class="link2">map</a>
    " 2.8 "
```

but not from here

```html
    <a href="http://scedc.caltech.edu/recent/Maps/118-36.html" class="link2">map</a>
    <font color="red">3.1</font>
```

```py
    soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    tags = soup.find_all("a",{'class': 'link2'})
    output=open("file.txt","w")

    for i in tags:

        if i.get_text()=="map":
            # prints each next_sibling
            print(i.next_sibling)
            # Extracts text if needed.
            try:
                output.write(i.next_sibling.get_text().strip()+"\n")
            except AttributeError:
                output.write(i.next_sibling.strip()+"\n")
    output.close()
```

The program writes all of the numbers that are not in red, and leaves empty spaces where there are red numbers. I want it to show everything.

Comment: Can you post a larger part of `soup` where these `<a>` tags are located?

Comment: Use `i.find_next_sibling('font')`

Comment: Soup is basically made out of repeats of the two examples as well as some irrelevant tags with other numbers and data that are not being processed.

Comment: @abdusco: how exactly would I implement that to show all of the data points in order, with numbers outside of font and inside of font together in the order they appear?

Comment: We need to know if these two `<a>`s are children of the same parent, siblings of each other or whatever the relationship is. So the context is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we can see more of your HTML tree there's probably a better way to do this but given the little bit of html that you've shown us, here's one way that will likely work.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<a href="http://scedc.caltech.edu/recent/Maps/118-36.html" class="link2">map</a>2.8
    <a href="http://scedc.caltech.edu/recent/Maps/118-37.html" class="link2">map</a>
    <font color="red">3.1</font>"""

soup=BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tags = soup.find_all("a",{'class': 'link2'})
output=open("file.txt","w")

for i in tags:
    if i.get_text()=="map":
        siblings = [sib for sib in i.next_siblings]
        map_sibling_text = siblings[0].strip()
        if map_sibling_text == '' and len(siblings) > 1:
            if siblings[1].name == 'font':
                map_sibling_text = siblings[1].get_text().strip()
        output.write("{0}\n".format(map_sibling_text))

output.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped alot.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how your HTML is overall. Is that classname always associated with an `a` tag for example? You might be able to do the following. Requires bs4 4.7.1.

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''

<a href="http://scedc.caltech.edu/recent/Maps/118-36.html" class="link2">map</a>
    " 2.8 "
<a href="http://scedc.caltech.edu/recent/Maps/118-36.html" class="link2">map</a>
<font color="red">3.1</font>

'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
data = [item.next_sibling.strip() if item.name == 'a' else item.text.strip()  for item in soup.select('.link2:not(:has(+font)), .link2 + font')]
print(data)
```